# Why does my XML code fail at getAttribute?

Tags: javascript, xml, titanium, appcelerator

Anyone shed any light onto why this doesn't work?!

I've been at it for days now, I admit to being a bit of a newbie.

I tried this as javascript in a browser with a captured set of the data and it was fine.

Converted it to work in Appcelerator Titanium and it just craps out when it gets to the getAttribute, no matter how I try and format it.

Someone said it was the data coming in but that seems to be ok, has to be me, its working for thousands of other people.

Anyone help get me out of this rut and tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
var xhr = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient();

xhr.onload = function()
{
var xmlDoc = this.responseXML.documentElement;
var xlinestatus=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('LineStatus');
var xline=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('Line');
var xstatus=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('Status');
var newname = '';

for (i=0;i<xlinestatus.length;i++)
{
Ti.API.info(i);
newname = xlinestatus.getElementsByTagName("Line ID")[0].getAttribute("Name");
// newname = xlinestatus[i].getAttribute('Name');
Ti.API.info(newname);
// Ti.API.info(': ' + '</b>');
// Ti.API.info(xstatus[i].getAttribute("Description"));
// Ti.API.info("<br />");
// Ti.API.info(xlinestatus[i].getAttribute("StatusDetails"));
// Ti.API.info("<br />");
// Ti.API.info("<br />");
}

};

// open the client

xhr.open('GET','http://cloud.tfl.gov.uk/TrackerNet/LineStatus');
// xhr.open('GET','demodata.xml');


// send the data
xhr.send();
```

Comment: Is the XML perfectly valid? Have you validated it with an XML validator?

Comment: It seems unlikely that you have a tag called "Line ID" on which to call getAttribute()...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var xhr = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient();

xhr.onload = function() {
   var xmlDoc = Ti.XML.parseString(this.responseText).documentElement;
   var xlinestatus = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('LineStatus');

   for (i = 0; i < xlinestatus.length; i++) {
     var theItem = xlinestatus.item(i);
     var newname = theItem.getElementsByTagName("Line").item(0).getAttribute("Name");
     var desc = theItem.getElementsByTagName("Status").item(0).getAttribute("Description");
     var active = theItem.getElementsByTagName("Status").item(0).getAttribute("IsActive");
     Ti.API.info(" Line: " + newname + " Status: " + desc + ", Active: " + active);
   }

};

// open the client
xhr.open('GET', 'http://cloud.tfl.gov.uk/TrackerNet/LineStatus');

// send the data
xhr.send({});
```

provided this output

```
[INFO] Line: Bakerloo Status: Good Service, Active: true
[INFO] Line: Central Status: Good Service, Active: true
[INFO] Line: Circle Status: Minor Delays, Active: true
[INFO] Line: District Status: Severe Delays, Active: true
[INFO] Line: Hammersmith and City Status: Minor Delays, Active: true
[INFO] Line: Jubilee Status: Good Service, Active: true
[INFO] Line: Metropolitan Status: Part Suspended, Active: true
[INFO] Line: Northern Status: Good Service, Active: true
[INFO] Line: Piccadilly Status: Minor Delays, Active: true
[INFO] Line: Victoria Status: Good Service, Active: true
[INFO] Line: Waterloo and City Status: Good Service, Active: true
```

Comment: Thank you so much Aaron, I will wade through this and understand where I went went wrong and learn from this. Thank you.

Comment: I still can't get the StatusDetails from the LineStatus. Obviously I am having issues traversing the tree. How do I get that info?

Comment: It may be empty at the moment but it normally has some data in it. How do I extract that data when it is available? I tried this: http://www.pastie.org/1679225

Answer (score 1):

In this line:

```
newname = xlinestatus.getElementsByTagName("Line ID")[0].getAttribute("Name");
```

The XML doesn't have an element called "Line ID".  It's an element called "Line" that has an attribute called "ID":

```
<Line ID="1" Name="Bakerloo"/>
```

Comment: If I change the typo, I get this:message = "Result of expression 'xlinestatus.getElementsByTagName(\"Line\")' [null] is not an object.";
name = TypeError;

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Titanium framework, but it looks to me that xlinestatus is probably an array, so you would need to do something like xlinestatus[i].getElementsByTagName("Line")...

Comment: This answer is wrong, as in the Titanium framework, getElementsByTagName doesn't return an array. See answer from Aaron that uses .item().